# Flutter: Put textField at bottom of scaffold

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

This has been giving me a headache, im just trying to put a Textfield on the bottom of my screen. I have the following code, trying to wrap it in a Positioned:

```
return Scaffold(

              //set a textField to add a reply

              appBar: TopAppBar(title: 'bruh'),
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    FocalWaveTile(
                      wave: widget.waveTile.wave,
                      user: profileState.user,
                      poster: widget.waveTile.poster,
                    ),
                    ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: waves.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        
                      },
                    ),
                    //poisition on the bottom
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Reply to this wave'),
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    if (value.length > 0) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isTyping = true;
                                      });
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        isTyping = false;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ));
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Any idea what im doing wrong? Ive tried a few things like a bottomnavbar and adding a spacer, but neither of these work in the way i would like them too. Thanks!

Comment: You are in a SingleChildScrollView. You can't put it down. Remove that and add a Spacer() above your widget.

Comment: Positioned is for Stack widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate everyone's help, but for some reason just replacing the singleChildScrollView with Listview solved it

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 return Scaffold(
  //set a textField to add a reply

  appBar: TopAppBar(title: 'bruh'),
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FocalWaveTile(
              wave: widget.waveTile.wave,
              user: profileState.user,
              poster: widget.waveTile.poster,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: waves.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {},
            ),
            //poisition on the bottom
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration:
                        InputDecoration(hintText: 'Reply to this wave'),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      if (value.length > 0) {
                        setState(() {
                          isTyping = true;
                        });
                      } else {
                        setState(() {
                          isTyping = false;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bottomNavigationBar`  from `Scaffold`.

```dart
Scaffold(
  bottomNavigationBar: TextFormField(),
```